# Clear Cookies for my WebView2 Instance in C#

Tags: c#, cookies, webview, webview2

I have a small application that logins into a website and performs some actions.  I need a method to clear the cookies and essentially "Force" logout of the website so I can perform the actions again.  The easiest way is to just clear the cookies and then repeat the login process, but I haven't been able to figure out how.  I have found this resource from Microsoft but I haven't been able to locate any sample code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2cookiemanager.deleteallcookies?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37

I believe WebView2 and Edge are closely related and also want to make sure by doing this I do not end up clearing the cookies on their main browser if they use Edge

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you have a WebView2 class you can do the following to clear cookies and reload the page:

```cs
// Clear cookies for this WebView2 and all WebView2s
// sharing the same user data folder.
webview2.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.DeleteAllCookies();
// Reload the document after clearing cookies
webview2.CoreWebView2.Reload();
```

The above code must be run after the WebView2 has finished initializing its CoreWebView2.

When you create a CoreWebView2 it belongs to a user data folder and browser process. Changing cookies via the CookieManager applies to all CoreWebView2s sharing the same profile and that user data folder.

You cannot share state between the WebView2 and the browser so you will not be modifying cookies in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Private mode?
[MSDN interface ICoreWebView2ControllerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2controlleroptions?view=webview2-1.0.1343.22#put_isinprivatemodeenabled)

You can clear cookies only dispose instance.